# Python Addin Wizard Combobox scripting help with zooming to selection

Tags: arcpy, python-addin, combo-box

I am coding an addin to allow me to use 3 comboboxes to select specific regions within a state. Once these are all selected in the comboboxes I need a final button to zoom to the selected area, indicated by the comboboxes. I am not sure how to get the selections from the three comboboxes to all be passed on to the zoom button so that it will zoom to the correct selected region.

Below is my code:

```
import arcpy
import pythonaddins

class SectionComboBoxClass35(object):
    """Implementation for SEC_TWN_RNG_2_addin.combobox (ComboBox)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10" ,"11", "12", "13", "14",
        "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31",
        "32", "33", "34", "35", "36"]
        self.editable = True
        self.enabled = True
        self.dropdownWidth = 'WWWWWW'
        self.width = 'WWWWWW'
    def onSelChange(self, selection):
        pass
    def onEditChange(self, text):
        pass
    def onFocus(self, focused):
        pass
    def onEnter(self):
        pass
    def refresh(self):
        pass

class TownshipComboBoxClass36(object):
    """Implementation for SEC_TWN_RNG_2_addin.combobox_1 (ComboBox)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14",
        "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30",
        "31","32", "32", "33", "34", "35"]
        self.editable = True
        self.enabled = True
        self.dropdownWidth = 'WWWWWW'
        self.width = 'WWWWWW'
    def onSelChange(self, selection):
        pass
    def onEditChange(self, text):
        pass
    def onFocus(self, focused):
        pass
    def onEnter(self):
        pass
    def refresh(self):
        pass

class TownshipDirectionComboBoxClass37(object):
    """Implementation for SEC_TWN_RNG_2_addin.combobox_2 (ComboBox)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = ["N", "S", "E", "W"]
        self.editable = True
        self.enabled = True
        self.dropdownWidth = 'WWWWWW'
        self.width = 'WWWWWW'
    def onSelChange(self, selection):
        pass
    def onEditChange(self, text):
        pass
    def onFocus(self, focused):
        pass
    def onEnter(self):
        pass
    def refresh(self):
        pass

class RangeComboBoxClass38(object):
    """Implementation for SEC_TWN_RNG_2_addin.combobox_3 (ComboBox)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14",
        "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30",
        "31","32", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45"]
        self.editable = True
        self.enabled = True
        self.dropdownWidth = 'WWWWWW'
        self.width = 'WWWWWW'
    def onSelChange(self, selection):
        pass
    def onEditChange(self, text):
        pass
    def onFocus(self, focused):
        pass
    def onEnter(self):
        pass
    def refresh(self):
        pass

class RangeDirectionComboBoxClass39(object):
    """Implementation for SEC_TWN_RNG_2_addin.combobox_4 (ComboBox)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = ["N", "S", "E", "W"]
        self.editable = True
        self.enabled = True
        self.dropdownWidth = 'WWWWWW'
        self.width = 'WWWWWW'
    def onSelChange(self, selection):
        pass
    def onEditChange(self, text):
        pass
    def onFocus(self, focused):
        pass
    def onEnter(self):
        pass
    def refresh(self):
        pass

class ZoomButtonClass40(object):

    def onClick(self):
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
        df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
        addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r'T:\Software\ESRI-GIS\toolbars\sec-twn-rng\KDAGISEDITOR.plss.lyr')
        arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, addLayer, "AUTO_ARRANGE")
    """Implementation for Zoom.button (Button)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = False
    def onClick(self):
        pass
        # Implementation of OnClick method of Button's class
    def onClick(self):
        # Get the current map document and the first data frame.
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('current')
        df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
        # Call the zoomToSelectedFeatures() method of the data frame class
        df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably are going to want to form a where clause out of the comboboxes.  You can get at the [value of the combobox](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#/Combo_Box/014p00000024000000/) by looking at the [docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) of your class to get the actual combobox object's value by the name you see there.  So in this example:

```
class RangeComboBoxClass38(object):
    """Implementation for SEC_TWN_RNG_2_addin.combobox_3 (ComboBox)"""
    def __init__(self):
        # stuff
```

The name of the combobox object is `combobox_3`, so to get at the value you can simply use `combobox_3.value`.

So using this knowledge, you can form a where clause with your `addLayer` variable. I'm just making this up but you could do something like this in your `ZoomButtonClass40.onClick()` method:

```
field_name = 'SEC' # name of field to search 
delimited = arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(addLayer, field_name)
where = '{} = {}{}'.format(delimited, combox_2.value, combobox_3.value) #concatenate the values of combobox_2 and combobox_3
arcpy.management.SelectLayerByLocation(addLayer, 'NEW_SELECTION', where)
df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()
```